# Using an ES6 Map with React and MobX doesn't rerender on all changes

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am in the process of learning mobx and am trying to do something that I think is fairly simple... I have a Map object in my store and created a findOrCreate action, but it doesn't seem like mobx is triggering rerenders in some cases.

I've created an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/0y1v181z1v

I initially log the size of the map which starts at 0, then call the findAndCreate method log the created object, and then call size.  The following call to size correctly reflects the change, but the initial call still shows 0. Once the "add item" button is clicked and another item is added, both sizes correctly reflect the number of items in the map.

--

To clarify one of the comments, I use the find or create in the render because the form fields in my actual project exist depending on the props passed down to the parent. There are several different "types" of forms that are all rendered by a single component and the fields are created depending on several different props. The suggestion to create them in the componentDidMount method is valid, but what if I were using an SFC? https://codesandbox.io/s/k10jylk1y3

Comment: Why are you invoking `findOrCreateItem` directly inside the render method? That's probably not what you want. If you instead invoke it in e.g. [`componentDidMount` it works as expected](https://codesandbox.io/s/zk8r04l16l).

Comment: @Tholle The specific example is simplified, but I have several form fields that variably exist based on props passed from a parent component. What if I am using a stateless functional component and don't have the lifecycle methods? https://codesandbox.io/s/k10jylk1y3

Comment: Then I think it's worth taking a step back and rethink the approach a bit. You are not supposed to change observables directly in on render, just as you shouldn't invoke `this.setState` directly on render.

Answer (score 0):

With React you **shouldn't**, nor do you need to, setState (or store) within render().

> The suggestion to create them in the componentDidMount method is valid, but what if I were using an SFC

When you want to use lifecycle methods you need to use "Statefull" aka "Class" components or React Hooks (since 16.8)

**Class Component example by @Tholle**

https://codesandbox.io/s/zk8r04l16l

**Hooks example in SFC/FunctionComponent**

```
const App: React.FunctionComponent = observer(({ store }) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
       store.findOrCreateItem("test");
    }, []);
    return (
            <div>
                <div>ittr items</div>
                {Array.from(store.map$).map(([key, value]) => (
                    <div key={key}>
                        item[{key}]: {value}
                    </div>
                ))}
                <div>store.size: {store.map$.size}</div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={store.addItem}>add item</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
});
```